# Will writing C in both Windows and Linux cause compiling problems?

Tags: linux, windows, cross-compiling

I work from 2 different machines. One is Windows and the other is Linux. If I alternately work on the same project but switch between both OSes, will I eventually run into compiling errors? I ask because maybe there are standards supported by one but not by the other.

Comment: You might want to use GCC on both machines.

Comment: And you could use a cross-platform library like GTk or its Glib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That question is a pretty broad one and it depends, strictly speaking, on your tool chain. If you were to use the same tool chain (e.g. GCC/MinGW or Clang), you'd be minimizing the chance for this class of errors. If you were to use Visual Studio on Windows and GCC or Clang on the Linux side, you'd run into more issues alone because some of the headers differ. So once your program leaves the realm of strict ANSI C (C89) you'll be on your own.

However, if you aren't careful you may run into a lot of other more profane errors, such as the compiler on Linux choking on the line endings if you didn't tell your editor on the Windows side to use these.

Ah, and also keep in mind that if you want to actually cross-compile, GCC may be the best choice and therefore the first part I mentioned in my answer becomes a moot point. GCC is a proven choice on both ends. And given your question it's unlikely that you are trying to write something like a kernel mode driver - which would be fundamentally different.

Comment: I installed MinGW in Eclipse. I hope everything works as intended.

Answer (score 2):

That may be only if your application use some specific API.

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely possible to write code that works on both platforms, with no issues to compile the code. It is, however, not without some difficulties. Compilers allow you to use non-standard features in the compiler, and it's often hard to do more fancy user interfaces (even if it's still just text) because as soon as you start wanting to do more than "read a line of text as it is entered in a shell", it's into "non-standard" land.

If you do find yourself needing to do more than what the standard C library can do, make sure you isolate those parts of the code into a separate file (or a couple of files, one for Linux/Unix style systems and one for Windows systems).

Using the same compiler (gcc) would help avoiding problems with "compiler B doesn't compile code that works fine in compiler A".

But it's far from an absolute necessity - just make sure you compile the code on both platforms and with all of your "suppoerted" compilers often enough that you haven't dug a very deep hole that is hard to get out of before you discover that "it's not working on the other system". It certainly helps if you have (at least) a virtual machine running the other OS, so you can easily try both variants.

Ideally, you want to set up an automated system, such that when you change the code [and feel that the changes are "complete"], it automatically gets built on both platforms and all compilers you want to use. And if possible, also automatically tested!

I would also seriously consider using version control - that way, when something breaks on one or the other side, you can go back and look at what the code looked like before it stopped working, and (hopefully) find the reason it broke much quicker than "Hmm, I think it's the change I made to foo.c, lets take that out... No, not that one, ok how about the change here..." - at least with version control, you can say "Ok, so version 1234 doesn't work, let's try version 1220 - ok, that works. Now try 1228, still works - so change between 1229 and 1234 - try 1232, ah, it's broken..." No editing files and you can still go to any other version you like with very little difficulty. I have used Mercurial quite a bit, git a little bit, some subversion, and worked on a project in Perforce for a few years. All of these are good - personally, I think I prefer mercurial.

As a side-effect: Most version control systems also deal with filename and line endings in the saner way than doing this manually.

If you combine your version control system with a "automated build and test-system", such as Jenkins, you can get everything very automated. Jenkins is free and runs on both Windows and Linux, and you can use it to automatically build and test your code as and when you submit the code to the version control system.

Answer (score 0):

It will not create a problem until you recompile the source code in the respective OS. If you wanna run your compiled file generated by windows(.exe or .obj), into linux or vice-versa then it will definitely create a problem and wont be possible.  But you can move you source code (file with extension .c/.c++) into any of the os. And sometimes it also create problems with different header files, so take care of that also. Best practice is to use single OS for you entire project, avoid multiple os until it is extremely necessary.

Comment: best practice for what? Excuse me, but I am maintaining more than a dozen projects across a variety of platforms and architectures (AIX, Solaris, BSDs, Linux, Windows ... x86, PPC, SPARC ...) how is it best practice to stay on one system? At least at the beginning you'll end up having to do a lot of tinkering to iron out some issues, but it becomes smoother with time and growing experience.